# How to store offset in the base array of this MIPS code?

Tags: c, mips

I stuck on this problem. I am given a C code and I need to convert it to MIPS.

Here is the C code:

```
for (c = 0; c < a; c++)
    for (d = 0; d < b; d++)
        D[8*d] = c + d;
```

assume the values of a, b, c, d are in the registers $s0, $s1, $t0, and $t1. Also the register $s2 contains the base address of array D.

Here is my following MIPS code so far:

```
       add   $t0, $zero,  $zero     # initialize c = 0
LOOP1: slt   $t2, $t0,    $s0       # temp reg $t2 = 1 if $t0 < $s0
       beq   $t2, $zero,  DONE      # if $t2 = 0, go to DONE
       add   $t1, $zero,  $zero     #initialize d = 0
LOOP2: slt   $t3, $t1,    $s1       # temp reg $t3 = 0 if $t1 < $s1
       beq   $t3, $zero,  L1        # if $t3 = 0, jump to L1 (current iteration of
                                    #LOOP1)
       sll   $t1, $t1,    3         # $t1 = $t1 << 8 where (8 * d)

       ????

       addi  $t1, $t1,    1         # increment d = d + 1
       j     LOOP2                  # jump back to LOOP2
  L1:  addi  $t0, $t0,    1         # increment c = c + 1
       J     LOOP1                  # jump back to LOOP1
DONE:
```

Where I'm stuck is in the "????" because I dont know how to store $t1 containing 8*d, back into $s2.

Thanks

Comment: SORRY GUYS I MAKE A MISTAKE, I'm fixing now, please wait. THanks

Comment: ok i fixed C code, thanks for patient

Comment: I suggest compiling a MIPS-gcc toolchain and using that for your C-to-MIPs conversion needs.  GCC can produce an assembly listing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that you overwrite the value that's in `d` every time through `LOOP2` - with the statement `sll   $t1, $t1,    3` you're saying 'replace d with d * 8'. You should store that in another temp register so you don't clobber your loop counter - ie. `sll   $t4, $t1,    3`.

Next you need to figure out what the address `D[8 * d]` is. Since you already have 8 * d stored in register `$t4`, it's just a matter of adding those two registers together - `add $t5, $s2, $t4`. Now, `$t5` contains the address you need to store into.

The only things left are computing the value and storing it - to compute it is simple, it's just `c + d` so all you need is to store that in another temp register - `add $t6, $t0, $t1`.

Now, `$t6` contains the value, and `$t5` the address. You just need to store `$t6` into `$t5` - `sw $t6, ($t5)`.

Comment: thanks Commander!....Sorry stupid mistake!...a question I have, for add $t5, $s2, $t2, dont you mean $t4 instead of $t2?

Comment: Yes, definitely - my mistake ;) edited. if it fixed your problem, it makes people feel good when you click the check mark beside the answer (I love points! =D )